# Reconnect RTSP stream in Gstreamer pipeline

Tags: c, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, nvidia-deepstream

I have a working Gstreamer pipeline using RTSP input streams. To handle these given RTSP input streams, the uridecobin element is used.

My goal is to reconnect to the RTSP input streams when internet connection is unstable.
When the internet connection is down for only few seconds and then it is up, then the pipeline starts to receive the frames again and everything is ok. When the internet connection is down for >20 seconds I get GST_MESSAGE_EOS. I tried to find some **timeout** variable in every element generated by uridecodebin, but I did not find it. Do you have any hint which element has this **timeout** variable and how to set it?

If it is not possible to set such **timeout** variable, is there any way to block GST_MESSAGE_EOS? Because when I receive GST_MESSAGE_EOS in bus, I try to remove uridecodebin from the pipeline and create a new one. But it does not work for me when GST_MESSAGE_EOS is received (When I try to remove uridecodebin from the pipeline and create a new one during normal state, it works).

Comment: Debugging this now. The timeout of 25 seconds seems to be 5 x the RTCP timeout, at which point a GstRTSPSrcTimeout will be fired. This 25 second timeout does not seem to be configurable.

Answer (score 2):

I found the way how to block GST_MESSAGE_EOS.

Create the following function to drop GST_EVENT_EOS:

```
GstPadProbeReturn eos_probe_cb(GstPad *pad, GstPadProbeInfo *info, gpointer u_data)
{
    if (GST_EVENT_TYPE(GST_PAD_PROBE_INFO_DATA(info)) == GST_EVENT_EOS)
    {
        return GST_PAD_PROBE_DROP;
    }
    return GST_PAD_PROBE_OK;
}
```

And then just add this function to some GstPad of your elements:

```
gst_pad_add_probe(src_pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_EVENT_DOWNSTREAM, eos_probe_cb,  (gpointer) user_data, NULL);
```